# How can I fix this SQL program?

Tags: sql-server

I found this SQL on internet but it is giving me some errors and I don't know how to fix it?

Can I have help with this SQL please?

```sql
Create Table Veterinarians
(vetName varchar2(20),
vid Number(5) primary key);


Create Table Dogs
(dogName varchar2(20),
did Number(5) primary key);


Create Table Location
(lid Number(5) primary key,
locName varchar2(20),);


Create Table Examine
(vid int foreign key references Veterinarians(vid),
did int foreign key references Dogs(did),
lid int foreign key references Location(lid),
fee Number(5));

INSERT INTO Veterinarians VALUES ('Alice',112);
INSERT INTO Veterinarians VALUES ('Mary',211);
INSERT INTO Veterinarians VALUES ('Jim',111);

INSERT INTO Dogs VALUES ('Spot',324);
INSERT INTO Dogs VALUES ('Fido',582);
INSERT INTO Dogs VALUES ('Tiger',731);

INSERT INTO Location VALUES (1001,'St.Cloud');
INSERT INTO Location VALUES (1002,'Minneapolis');
INSERT INTO Location VALUES (1003,'Duluth');

INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (111,324,1001,10);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (111,731,1003,20);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (112,324,1001,30);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (112,582,1001,50);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (112,731,1002,35);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (211,324,1001,25);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (211,582,1002,35);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (211,731,1001,20);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (211,582,1001,25);
INSERT INTO Examine VALUES (211,582,1003,65);

--Creating a stored procedure
Create PROCEDURE display_Avg(vid int) AS
BEGIN
select v.vid,v.vetName,Avg(e.fee) as AverageFee
from Veterinarians v
INNER JOIN Examine e
ON v.vid=e.vid
Where v.vid=display_Avg.vid
Group By v.vid,v.vetName;
END;

--Executing stored procedure
Execute display_Avg(112);

CREATE PROCEDURE display_DogNames 
AS BEGIN
select dogName
from Dogs
INNER JOIN Examine
ON Examine.did=Dogs.did
INNER JOIN Location
On Examine.lid=Location.lid
Where Location.lid=1001
AND Location.lid=1002
AND Location.lid=1003
END;
```

Here are the errors it is giving me

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure display_Avg, Line 46 [Batch
> Start Line 0] Incorrect syntax near 'vid'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure display_Avg, Line 57 [Batch
> Start Line 0] Incorrect syntax near '112'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure display_Avg, Line 60 [Batch
> Start Line 0] 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in
> a query batch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
    CREATE TABLE Veterinarians (
      vetName varchar(20),
      vid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
    
    
    CREATE TABLE Dogs (
      dogName varchar(20),
      did int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
    
    
    CREATE TABLE tblLocation (
      lid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      locName varchar(20)
    );
    
    
    CREATE TABLE Examine (
      vid int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Veterinarians (vid),
      did int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Dogs (did),
      lid int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblLocation (lid),
      fee int
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Veterinarians
      VALUES ('Alice', 112);
    INSERT INTO Veterinarians
      VALUES ('Mary', 211);
    INSERT INTO Veterinarians
      VALUES ('Jim', 111);
    
    INSERT INTO Dogs
      VALUES ('Spot', 324);
    INSERT INTO Dogs
      VALUES ('Fido', 582);
    INSERT INTO Dogs
      VALUES ('Tiger', 731);
    
    INSERT INTO tblLocation
      VALUES (1001, 'St.Cloud');
    INSERT INTO tblLocation
      VALUES (1002, 'Minneapolis');
    INSERT INTO tblLocation
      VALUES (1003, 'Duluth');
    
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (111, 324, 1001, 10);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (111, 731, 1003, 20);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (112, 324, 1001, 30);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (112, 582, 1001, 50);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (112, 731, 1002, 35);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (211, 324, 1001, 25);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (211, 582, 1002, 35);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (211, 731, 1001, 20);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (211, 582, 1001, 25);
    INSERT INTO Examine
      VALUES (211, 582, 1003, 65);
    
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.display_Avg') > 0
      DROP PROCEDURE dbo.display_Avg
    GO
    
    --Creating a stored procedure
    CREATE PROCEDURE display_Avg (@vid int)
    AS
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        v.vid,
        v.vetName,
        AVG(e.fee) AS AverageFee
      FROM Veterinarians v
      INNER JOIN Examine e
        ON v.vid = e.vid
      WHERE v.vid = @vid
      GROUP BY v.vid,
               v.vetName;
    END;
    
    --Executing stored procedure
    EXECUTE display_Avg 112;
    
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.display_DogNames') > 0
        DROP PROCEDURE dbo.display_DogNames
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE display_DogNames
    AS
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        dogName
      FROM Dogs
      INNER JOIN Examine
        ON Examine.did = Dogs.did
      INNER JOIN tblLocation
        ON Examine.lid = tblLocation.lid
      WHERE tblLocation.lid = 1001
      AND tblLocation.lid = 1002
      AND tblLocation.lid = 1003
    END;

    EXEC display_DogNames
```

The modifications are:

1.-Type is VARCHAR not varchar2

2.-For the primary key its INTEGER and not need the long like "int (5)"

3.-Add not null in primary keys for not accept nulls

4.-Changue the name of Location to tblLocation in case "Location" be a reserv word by SQL

5.-Destroy the object before creat:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.display_DogNames')> 0
      DROP PROCEDURE dbo.display_DogNames
    GO
```

6.-The params in the procedure have an @ before the name of the param: @vid

7.-Finally to excecute an procedure you don't need the "()" symbols: EXECUTE display_Avg 112;

If you want to drop the tables, remember doing in orden keeping in mind the foreign key:

1- drop table Examine

2- drop table tblLocation

3- drop table Veterinarians

4- drop table Dogs

Comment: @Joliage Does this fit your needs? Any questions? Care to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why start with a script that you cannot run and cannot debug. Find a sample database that is well-defined and use it for learning to write tsql queries. That approach will also avoid the problems with attempting to design a database without a proper foundation of relational knowledge. MS has published the sample databases [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples).

But that probably won't deter you, so the solution is to break your script into batches. Quite simply add a line containing "GO" before every "create procedure" statement as well as one immediately after the creation of the first procedure since it is followed by an execute statement for that same procedure.

```
GO  -- **HERE**

--Creating a stored procedure
Create PROCEDURE display_Avg(vid int) AS
BEGIN
select v.vid,v.vetName,Avg(e.fee) as AverageFee
from Veterinarians v
INNER JOIN Examine e
ON v.vid=e.vid
Where v.vid=display_Avg.vid
Group By v.vid,v.vetName;
END;

GO  -- **HERE**

--Executing stored procedure
Execute display_Avg(112);

GO  -- **HERE**

CREATE PROCEDURE display_DogNames 
AS BEGIN
select dogName
from Dogs
INNER JOIN Examine
ON Examine.did=Dogs.did
INNER JOIN Location
On Examine.lid=Location.lid
Where Location.lid=1001
AND Location.lid=1002
AND Location.lid=1003
END;
```